# Get offset of selection text

Tags: jquery, html

I have html codes like

```
<div id="content">
   <span class="pivot">1</span>
   I know this is a really simple
   <span class="pivot">2</span>
   question
   <span class="pivot">3</span>
   to answer 
   <span class="pivot">4</span>
   please 
   <span class="pivot">5</span>
   help me to solve.
</div>
```

I select the text and I want to get the start_index (this case = 0) and last_index (this case = 39) of this text in *the whole text without span of class `pivot`*

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7bxp/1/

Comment: Can you trigger the parsing with some button or something else after selecting?<br>Or will you always select the first sentence?

Comment: @AlanPiralla I will trigger by click a button? have a solution?

Comment: @gvee i have looked at this question. And i used this code. It returns start and last, but that isn;t thing i need. Because it includes the text within span class pivot in calculation, while i dont want to count it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should give you a go:

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}



$('#your_button').click(function() {
   var whole_text = $('#content').text();
   var selected_text = getSelectionText();
   var index_of = whole_text.indexOf(selected_text);
   var end_of = index_of + selected_text.length;
});
```

I took the function from here: [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)

here's a working jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a7bxp/

Comment: It returns 0. The selected_text is null. And index_of = 0.

Comment: opps, i dont want to include the text in span.pivot in the selected_text and also the whole_text. The span is just a pivot to separate the string for some reason.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a7bxp/1/

Comment: In that case you should adapt it somehow if you want to keep your original html structure.<br>

Comment: I want to keep my html structure too. Tha't problem.

Comment: Can you wrap the text you need to select into a different <span>? Like `<span class="sum_text">` In that case you could use a `each()` function to sum all the text into a variable then get its index.

Comment: well, that seems a good idea. I'll try.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991474/calculate-position-of-selected-text-javascript-jquery] i used this code highlighted on this question, but it wrapped also the pivot.

Comment: Also, if you want to exclude the text inside `pivot` from your selection, you should be aware that `indexOf` returns -1 if it doesn't find the text. In that case use an `if` to avoid calculating the `end_of`. For example if you select some text inside a `pivot`.

Comment: Finally, i've to use php to handle this problem. :-s