# UWP WebView: add tags to selected text

Tags: javascript, c#, html, webview, uwp

Here's the problem I'm stuck with. I'm creating an UWP app that uses `WebView` (on Windows 10, so it's Edge) to edit some html. To do so I wrap the editable content into editable `<div>`, let user edit it and unwrap the content afterwards. Unfortunately I can't come up with a way to implement "make selection bold/make selection italic/..." functionality.

Does anyone know a way to do it in C# or in js? Getting selection, replacing it with the same text with tags and reloading webview from string won't do, 'cause obviously the selected block could be found more than once in a text and/or could be complex.

If someone knows how to do it without 3rd party libraries or with libraries under MIT or gpl2 licenses, it would be beyond awesome.

Comment: What have you tried? I don't believe the `WebView` exposes the selected text, which I guess is what you want. I think you'll need to look for a different control to edit the HTML.

Comment: `WebView` exposes selected text either by `.CaptureSelectedContentToDataPackageAsync()` or by calling js `.GetSelection()` As I mentioned, I tried working with selection but it lacks info about positioning - only text available.

Comment: Have your issues been resolved? And do you have any other updates?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT it got resolved but in a not related to code way. We dropped the text morphing feature for now (because full robust js solutions are a bit too heavy for our needs and UWP web view does not support these features by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description `js` is better for your scenario and you need calculate position of selected text at first. I write the following code refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991474/calculate-position-of-selected-text-javascript-jquery). In my sample I make the selected text bold.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DivTextDemo</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" contenteditable="true">Content goes here! This is Winffee, This is Winffee</div>
    <button id="btnClick">Click Me</button>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict"
    var myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
    var myRange = null;

    function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
        var start = 0, end = 0;
        var sel, range, priorRange;
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            priorRange = range.cloneRange();
            priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            start = priorRange.toString().length;
            end = start + range.toString().length;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
                (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
            priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
            start = priorRange.text.length;
            end = start + range.text.length;
        }
        return {
            start: start,
            end: end
        };
    }

    document.querySelector("#btnClick").onclick = function (evt)
    {
        var wholeText = document.querySelector("#myDiv").innerText;
        var positionObj = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(myDiv);
        var start = positionObj.start;
        var end = positionObj.end;
        //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = generateInnerHtml(positionObj.start, positionObj.end, wholeText);
        myDiv.innerHTML = wholeText.substr(0, start) + "<b>" + wholeText.substr(start, end - start) + "</b>" + wholeText.substr(end, wholeText.length);
    }

})();
```

Comment: I'll mark it as answer. It does not give a working universal solution but it does formally answer the question.